# Função com erro deepEqual

Tags: javascript, funções

Olá,

Estou no seguinte enunciado tentando completar:

*“Ah, mas isso não acaba aqui” - disse Ana “Eu quero saber em quantos meses houve lucro, ou seja, o saldo foi maior que zero” .
Complete a função quantidadeDeMesesComLucro.
Exemplo:
function quantidadeDeMesesComLucro(umPeriodo) {
let quantidade= ???;
for (let mes=0; mes< umPeriodo.length; mes++) {
???
}
return quantidade;
}*

E fiz o seguinte código:

```
function quantidadeDeMesesComLucro(umPeriodo){
let quantidade = 0;

for(let mes = 0; mes < umPeriodo.length; mes++){
    if(umPeriodo[mes] < 0)
        quantidade += 1;
}

return quantidade;
```

}

**E aparece os seguintes erros informando que a solução não passou completamente:**

x quantidadeDeMesesComLucro([1]) é 1

0 deepEqual 1

x quantidadeDeMesesComLucro([2, 20, 20]) é 3

0 deepEqual 3

x quantidadeDeMesesComLucro([10, -10, 2, 100]) é 3

0 deepEqual 3

*Alguém pode me ajudar? Grata!*

Comment: Não deveria ser `umPeriodo[mes] > 0` ao invés de `umPeriodo[mes] < 0`?

Comment: O erro permanece das 2 formas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não acho que essa questão precise de uma resposta, mas como a usuária diz que o código continua não funcionando mesmo com a correção na comparação, vou deixar o trecho de forma executável:

```js
function quantidadeDeMesesComLucro(umPeriodo){
  let quantidade = 0;

  for (let mes = 0; mes < umPeriodo.length; mes++) {
    // compara se o valor do array umPeriodo na posição mês é maior do que 0
    if (umPeriodo[mes] > 0)
      quantidade += 1;
  }

  return quantidade;
}

console.log(quantidadeDeMesesComLucro([1]));
console.log(quantidadeDeMesesComLucro([2, 20, 20]));
console.log(quantidadeDeMesesComLucro([10, -10, 2, 100]));
```

Como você pode ver, ele printa 1, 3 e 3, respectivamente, da forma que deveria.

Comment: user140828, grata! Desta forma solucionou na plataforma!